# Why is there a same transaction in two blocks in Ethereum (from Cloudflare provider)?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, cloudflare

I found a same transaction appeared in two blocks according to our app log files. It results in a primary key error in the database since we used `tx.hash` for PK column.

You will see transaction `0x1f755c38f032091736b4f331f7db77a04917d962078db57efc1e8156163c68bc` in both queries' responses below. How can it?

```bash
eth block:get 15365119 --network 'https://cloudflare-eth.com/v1/mainnet'
eth block:get 15365121 --network 'https://cloudflare-eth.com/v1/mainnet'
```

Transaction `0x1f755c38f032091736b4f331f7db77a04917d962078db57efc1e8156163c68bc` is in both blocks 15365119 and 15365121. While it's only in block 15365121 on [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1f755c38f032091736b4f331f7db77a04917d962078db57efc1e8156163c68bc) now.

Answer (score -1):

Likely reason is minor chain reorganization and Cloudflare responses being cached / out of sync.

However because the question is about third party commercial service provider, this issue should be answered by their customer support, not public forum where people try to guess what's wrong with private code.

Comment: It's a public and free service (with rate limiting).

Comment: Still, it is a question for Cloudflare support, because they are the only ones who know how they are running their Ethereum nodes - this information is not public.  Even if you are not paying anything for Cloudflare it is a commercial service and in this case their monetisation model is just not to take money from you right now. Furthermore, if Cloudflare is not reliable then run your own Ethereum node.

Comment: Oh, so we should only ask questions about SO's services here :)

Comment: You can ask whatever you want, but no one from Cloudflare is here, to give you a proper answer.

Comment: Ok, I already got the answer and it isn't from Cloudflare.